# Prism Event Aggregator - always single instance?

Tags: c#, prism, eventaggregator

Does it has any sense to use two instance of EventAggregator - every to handle different events from diffrent areas of system ? Or it doesn't matter and for  subscribe any type of event and publish any type of event (even if the events are not connected from bussines point of view) using just single and the same instance of EventAggregator is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Having a scoped `EventAggregator` in a sense defeats its purpose, being to enable anyone to subscribe to any event.

That being said, your application might well benefit from scoped *events*, though. In that case, I'd put the events in different shared assemblies visible to different parts of your application (e.g. tiers). Think `UserLoggedInEvent` available to all ui modules, but not the database module, as opposed to a ui `EventAggregator` and another one for the database.